# How to replace system defined setting with user defined setting within info.plist file?

Tags: xcode, info-plist

Within `info.plist` there is system defined setting: **View controller-based status bar appearance**.

[image]

This is a Boolean option grayed out.

But in my project I use lot of targets and need to define this setting per target. So, I have defined `User Defined Setting` like this:

[image]

But when I try to replace `ON` with `$(CUSTOM_STATUS_BAR_APPEARANCE_ENABLED)` it doesn't work because the type is Boolean. If I force change that property within plist file like this:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<string>$(CUSTOM_STATUS_BAR_APPEARANCE_ENABLED)</string>
```

it still doesn't work. Why? How can I do that *without* creating separated plists?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with custom Run Script - in build time script can change value of bool in Info.plist -> in your conditions it should be like:

```
INFOPLIST="${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance NO" "${INFOPLIST}"
```

Hope that helps!